# Hough transform filter lines

Tags: math, opencv, graphics, geometry

I have applied the Hough transform algorithm provided by OpenCV to an image, and now I have an array of lines, each of them containing a `startPoint` and an `endPoint`. I saw that I have multiple lines that could be merged into single lines (based on their slope/distance).

How can I merge multiple lines that have the same slope?

Comment: You will need to run an iterator through the set of points and do a similarity check between the lines. You might try and and tweak the threshold, though; it would give slightly better results.

Comment: Please provide a sample image.

Answer (score 2):

A suggestion for a similarity score to compare two line segments:
 - join the middles of the line segments, giving you a straight line;
 - project the line segments onto this line;
 - express the four projected endpoints in terms of the abscissa along the line.

Design a score function that
 - is 0 when the two segments overlap;
 - is 0 when the gap segment intersects other line segments;
 - increases when the angle difference tends to 0 (could be the absolute value of the sine of the difference);
 - increases when the ratio of the gap between the projected endpoints over the sum of the lengths tends to 0.

Using such a similarity score you can merge the segments, for instance using a greedy process.